# What's the best way to compare the results of 2 Subselects on the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a better way to compare the result of 2 Sub-Selects on the same Table, than using 2 separate Queries?

In the following Query, I'd like to select all incidents where the "client" of the "creator" is not equal to the "client" of another user which I pass later on.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    incident i
WHERE
    i.client_id = 150
AND ( --can this AND be shortend?
    SELECT
        ur1.CLIENT_ID
    FROM
        USER ur1
    WHERE
        ur1.USER = upper(i.CREATOR)
) != (
    SELECT
        ur2.CLIENT_ID
    FROM
        USER ur2
    WHERE
        ur2.USER = upper('other')
)
```

Minimal reproducable example

- Users inside the USER-Table are always Uppercase
- Every User is unique
- 1 User can only have 1 Client_Id

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99ac066a9abd339cd9a80a5b78716138

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some example data; and the expected output for that sample data. Also, your query does not appear to work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e51ddf7198805c058727bd30c11e3f9).

Comment: @MT0 thanks for the advice I updated my Question with a reproducable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the constraints:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT
  user__id_user__pk PRIMARY KEY ("USER");

ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT
  user__id_user__u UNIQUE (client_id, "USER");

ALTER TABLE incident ADD CONSTRAINT
  incident__id_creator__fk FOREIGN KEY (client_id, creator)
  REFERENCES "USER" (client_id, "USER");
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   incident i
WHERE  i.client_id = 150
AND    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT u.client_id
         FROM   "USER" u
         WHERE  u."USER"    = upper('joe')
         AND    u.client_id = i.client_id
      )
```

---

If you do not have the foreign key constraint (and just have the unique/PK constraints on the `USER` table) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   incident i
WHERE  i.client_id = 150
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   "USER" u
         WHERE  u."USER"    IN (i.creator, upper('joe'))
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) > 1
      )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=93d180c0d9fc00cfa8b10ca4d6fe6812)*

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to the constraints. However the second solution resulted in a more efficient solution then the 2 Sub Selects. Would you mind giving a short Explanation why you're doing 2 counts in the HAVING Condition?

Comment: @Lavariet There was a reason if you have a creator in the `incident` table that does not exist in the `USER` table (which can happen since you do not have a foreign key between the two tables) and you are also comparing to another user that does not exist. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb90240a46a9116836b7bb73552f868a) However, it can be simplified to a single `COUNT(DISTINCT client_id)` with a greater than comparison so I've changed the query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe self join? Something like this:

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM incident i
       JOIN USER u1 ON u1.USER = i.creator
       JOIN USER u2 ON u2.client_id <> u1.client_id
 WHERE     i.client_id = 150
       AND u2.USER = 'OTHER'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked the execution plan, and it's quite heavy (since a unique is required and the Joins also have quite high cost compared to the sub select)
I'll keep it in mind that I can also join the tables instead of having to subselect in the where statement

Comment: You're welcome. Are columns (used in joins) indexed? If not, consider to do so.

Comment: yes they are, good hint

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way,

```
SELECT i.*
 FROM incident i, user ur1, user ur2
WHERE i.client_id = 150
  AND ur1.user =  UPPER(i.creator)
  AND ur2.user = UPPER(‘other’)
  AND ur1.client_id != ur2.client_id
```